# Why does Python Plotly function with barmode produce an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I have been trying to figure this out for a while, so any help would be appreciated.

I am able to run `fig_test_reg` just fine, but then when I try to run the same parameters through a function I get a ValueError: `ValueError: Value of 'pattern_shape' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['Fruit', 'Amount', 'City'] but received: group`

code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

def to_bar(data,x,y,color,barmode):
    bar_chart = px.bar(data,x,y,color,barmode)
    return bar_chart


fig_test_func = to_bar(df_test, x="Fruit", y="Amount",color='City',barmode='group')

fig_test_reg = px.bar(df_test, x="Fruit", y="Amount",color='City',barmode='group')

fig_test_func.show()
```

why is this happening? how can I run this through a function? what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is in how you are passing function arguments.  If you look at the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar.html) for the `.bar()` method, you can see the order of keyword arguments:

```
plotly.express.bar(
    data_frame=None,
    x=None,
    y=None, 
    color=None, 
    pattern_shape=None, 
    # more kwargs here
    barmode='relative',
    # more kwargs here
)
```

Inside your function, you are passing parameters as positional arguments, rather than keyword arguments: `bar_chart = px.bar(data,x,y,color,barmode)`. So, your `group` value that you are trying to pass to the `barmode=` parameter actually gets passed to the `pattern_shape=` parameter, as it is located in that fifth position in the function's signature.

So, to resolve the problem, you can just convert the positional arguments to keyword arguments in your call to the `px.bar()` function:

```
bar_chart = px.bar(data,x=x,y=y,color=color,barmode=barmode)
```

Comment: Ah ok, my intuition was that it must have had to do with the ordering, but I wasn't thinking of the positional vs keyword! Time to do some reading :)